# Configuring Set-Cookie in IIS

Tags: iis, cookies, asp-classic, http-headers, owasp

I have to set requireSSL flag in my Classic ASP Application.

Is it possible to set it in IIS using HTTP Response Header configuration?

I have configured "X-Frame-Options" in IIS so I am hoping there should be something similar like Set-Cookie - secure in IIS Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rahulso/2007/06/19/cookies-case-study-with-ssl-and-frames-classic-asp/

> **TL;DR** Now, enable SSL on your website. Open a command prompts and go to C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts
>   Issue the following command and reset IIS> adsutil set
>   w3svc/1/AspKeepSessionIDSecure 0.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2012/11/02/change-or-modify-a-response-header-value-using-url-rewrite/) is the tutorial for setting/replacing response header in IIS. You need to install  [HTTP Rewrite](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337) module first